# Compact Hausdorff space and closure

Tags: general-topology, compactness, separation-axioms

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space, let $A \subset X$ and let $U$ is open subset of $X$ such that $\overline A \subset U$. prove that there exist an open set $W$ such that $\overline A \subset W$ and $\overline W \subset U$.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 2):

$X$ is normal and $\overline{A}$ is closed. QED.

Comment: Very short proof! In case that others need more details I will add: Every compact Hausdorff space is normal. $X$ is normal if and only if given a closed set $A$ and an open set $U$ containing $A$, there is an open set $W$ containing $A$ such that $\overline W \subset U$.